# realmethods plugin for eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am trying to install [realmethods plugin](http://www.isw2.com/english/product/rM_news005040206.htm) in eclipse.
When I install realmethods it shows the following error

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: realMethods GAE Generator 1.0.0.201004110340 (aib_eclipse_feature.feature.group 1.0.0.201004110340)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.2.1.20090918-0703 (epp.package.jee 1.2.1.20090918-0703)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Common Navigator View 3.4.0.I20090525-2000 (org.eclipse.ui.navigator 3.4.0.I20090525-2000)
    Common Navigator View 3.4.2.M20100120-0800 (org.eclipse.ui.navigator 3.4.2.M20100120-0800)
    Common Navigator View 3.4.1.M20090911-1550 (org.eclipse.ui.navigator 3.4.1.M20090911-1550)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: realMethods GAE Generator 1.0.0.201004110340 (aib_eclipse_feature.feature.group 1.0.0.201004110340)
    To: org.eclipse.ui.navigator 3.4.2
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.2.1.20090918-0703 (epp.package.jee 1.2.1.20090918-0703)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.2.1.20090918-0703]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.2.1.20090918-0703 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.2.1.20090918-0703)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.5.1.R35x_v20090910-9gEeG1_FthkNDSP2odXdThaOu9GFDPn83DGB7]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.5.1.R35x_v20090910-9gEeG1_FthkNDSP2odXdThaOu9GFDPn83DGB7 (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.5.1.R35x_v20090910-9gEeG1_FthkNDSP2odXdThaOu9GFDPn83DGB7)
    To: org.eclipse.ui.navigator [3.4.1.M20090911-1550]
```

What shall I do. Can any one help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to pinpoint the exact requirements for the [RealMethods Framework](http://www.realmethods.com/).

[image]

The error message you have is one of the reasons [P2 is still not perfect](http://villane.wordpress.com/2009/06/26/p2-still-not-awesome/), as in:

[image]

> The root of the error message is on the fourth line, “Only one of the following can be installed at once”.
>   You are trying to install something that is incompatible with what you have installed (they require different versions of the Common Navigator View , but there can only be one version of that bundle installed at any given time).

So try with [different version of Eclipse Java EE editions](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/galileosr2) and see which one is compatible with RealMethods plugin.